# Confusion with $\epsilon-\delta$ constraints

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

I'm admittedly a bit embarrassed to ask this, but after completing real analysis I came to the realization that I don't actually understand the constraints of continuity as well actually I thought.

Say we're trying to prove $f(x) $ is continuous at $x = x_0$ using $\epsilon-\delta $. When choosing $\delta$, it is common to express it as a function of $\epsilon$ and $x_0$, and this part I'm okay with.

However, we *cannot* have it be a function of $x$, and I am struggling to understand why. I can see how it would lead to impossible results if we did, and some part of it is vaguely intuitive. But I have always considered intuition a parlor trick of sorts without having the proper justification behind it, and I'd like some help with clarification.

Comment: $\delta$ tells you how close the values of $x$ where the conclusion $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ holds must be to $x_0$. If it could depend on $x$, then continuity would be vacuous, just take $\delta=|x-x_0|/2$ and then the hypothesis of the implication never holds.

Answer (score 3):

$\delta$ technically isn't a function, it's a fixed constant.  It's a constant that depends on two other constants:  $\epsilon$ and $x_0$.

But $x$ is not a constant, it is a variable.  And since $\delta$ is (supposed to be) a constant, then $\delta$ can't depend on $x$.

Comment: I suppose I've always sort of viewed $\delta $ as a function of $\epsilon $, so perhaps that is where I went wrong. So when it is said that it holds "for all $\epsilon > 0$", does it mean that for each positive (fixed) $\epsilon $, there is a positive (fixed) $\delta$ which satisfies the relation?

Comment: Yes that is what it means.

Comment: @infinitylord, yes, that's correct.  That's also why proofs of statements that begin like "For all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that ..." typically begin with "Fix $\epsilon > 0$..." and eventually establish a $\delta$ that (most likely) depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. May I ask you a question now about continuity of functionals with $\epsilon-\delta $? That is where this whole confusion sprung up.

Comment: Functionals?  I probably won't be able to help with that.  I'd recommend making a new post for it.

Comment: $\delta$ is in a sense a function; converting a "for all x, there exists y such that P(x,y)" statement into "there exists f such that for all x, P(x,f(x))" is called Skolemization, and it is logically sound in many situations. (Of course one may stumble into issues related to the axiom of choice in the course of Skolemization.)

Comment: As already said, $\delta$ isn't a function, but something that is a function is the set of $\delta$ that works for a given $\epsilon$ (and $x_0$).

Comment: @infinitylord, if it helps, you can indeed *think* of $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$, but think of it more explicitly as a function $\delta : \{\epsilon\} \to \Bbb R_+$.  In other words, the domain of the "function" $\delta$ is the single constant value $\epsilon$ (with a similar interpretation for $\delta$ that depends on $\epsilon$ and $x_0$).

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of how the definition is stated.  To say that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ means that:

> For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$, if $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.

So, what's the difference between the role $\epsilon$ and the role of $x$?  The difference is that "for all $x$" comes **after** "there exists a $\delta>0$", whereas "for all $\epsilon>0$" comes before it.  This means that we pick $\epsilon$ before we pick $\delta$, but we pick $x$ after we pick $\delta$.  So $\delta$ can depend on $\epsilon$, because we know what $\epsilon$ is (it's some fixed number) before we get around to needing to pick $\delta$.  On the other hand, we pick $\delta$ before we know what $x$ is and our choice of $\delta$ needs to make the statement "if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$" be true for *all* $x$.  So we need a single $\delta$ that works for *every* $x$ at once; we can't use different $\delta$'s for different $x$'s.

The role of $x_0$ is similar to the role of $\epsilon$, except even more strongly so: the number $x_0$ is fixed from the very beginning.  In particular, it's fixed before we have to choose a $\delta$, so $\delta$ can depend on what $x_0$ is.

Comment: Thank you, I found it very helpful to consider the order in which they appear in the statement. Admittedly, I'm still a bit bothered by it in the sense that the order they are introduced in the statement seems arbitrary, but it certainly makes sense with how it's presented

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to prove continuity at a point $x_0$, the goal is to, for any fix $\epsilon>0$, find a single $\delta$ so that all values within $\delta$ of $x_0$ map to a point within $\epsilon$ of $f(x_0)$. That $\delta$ cannot be a function of $x$, because it is a single value (positive real number) which is associated with the point $x_0$.

$\delta$ is only a "function" in that for every $x_0$ and $\epsilon$ you choose, this $\delta$ may need to change. If the function is continuous at more than one point (as is usually the case) you may also have different $\delta$'s associated with different $x$ values. When proving continuity at an arbitrary $x$, you could view the expression that you get for $\delta$ (which may depend on $x$ or may not) to be a function of $x$, but still each $\delta$ which is outputted by this function is just one real number, and thus it doesn't really make sense for it to be a "function of $x$".